# Magento 2, bring category description at bottom of category page via update layout xml

Tags: magento2, categories, magento-layout-xml

In magento 2, there is a box in every category page to enter description that displays on top of products in category page, can it be brought at bottom somehow only via update layout xml coding which is under design tab, i want this approach only, i dont want to get file from server and modify core files.

OR

any other way we can display text based content at bottom of category page after products listings, this is for SEO.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please change according to below steps:

Go to **catalog_category_view.xml** file and paste below code before `<body>` tag end.

File Path:

> Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<move element="category.description" destination="content" after="category.products.list"/>
```